# Android studio starting screen different the it should be

Tags: android, android-studio

Just started learning android so i checked some online curses on how to set up my android studio project. The program version is up to date but i am getting a different new project screen the people do on videos. So i don't get to write the company domain, choose for what platform or pick the activity module. Tried to reinstall it but nothing changes. Not sure if i should/can continue the tutorials without that.  Probably is just a simple mistake somewhere buti cant seem to find it.

[1. picture of what android studio shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0x0.png)

[2. picture of what android studio shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M70Ef.png)

[3. picture of what android studio shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EuwJ.png)

Comment: they may be on an older version of android studio?

Answer (score 1):

Android projects are built by [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) build system nowadays. So you should select **Gradle** from the left menu and then slect the make the rest of your project configuration as you wish.